# Setup.py - Install all files to lib

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I currently have a file structure like this in an application I am building:

```
.
├── README.md
├── bin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── fix_sales_quotes.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logger.py
│   ├── oracle_dbx_connector
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── dbx_connector.py
│   │   └── timeout.py
│   └── sales_quote
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── data
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── get_processed_quotes.py
│       │   ├── get_stuck_quotes.py
│       │   ├── get_subscriber_ids.py
│       │   └── get_workflow_events.py
│       └── report.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── var
    ├── logs
    └── reports
```

My app has a few entry points in lib and bin depending on what I am trying to do and I am having problems installing all the setup files to lib so they are not hanging out in root and having the entry points still work. Below is part of my setup.py file and I wanted to see if I could get some guidance on how to still have entry points for bin and lib in each proper sub dir but have all the setup files installed to lib (like dist, build, env etc)

```
setup(
    name='fix_sq_issues',
    python_requires='~=3.7',
    description='Fix and report on Sales Quote issues',
    long_description='',
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
    ],
    author='Branden Connell',
    author_email='n@n.com',
    url='----',
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'sales_quote.stuck_quotes = lib.sales_quote.data.get_stuck_quotes:main',
            'sales_quote.processed_quotes = lib.sales_quote.data.get_processed_quotes:main',
            'sales_quote.subscriber_ids = lib.sales_quote.data.get_subscriber_ids:main',
            'sales_quote.workflow_events = lib.sales_quote.data.get_workflow_events:main',
            'sales_quote.report = lib.sales_quote.report:main',
            'sales_quote.fix = bin.fix_sales_quotes:entry_point'
        ]
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=requirements,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you follow another project layout. You should not try to make what you have right now install-able by setuptools.

[This](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/) is a great recommendation that is widely used